# Perl: passing regex search and replace using variables

Tags: regex, perl, capture

I have a Perl script that reads regex search and replace values from an INI file.

This works fine until I try to use capture variables ($1 or \1). These get replaced literally with $1 or \1.

Any ideas how I can get this capture functionality to work passing regex bits via variables? Example code (not using an ini file)...

```
$test = "word1 word2 servername summary message";

$search = q((\S+)\s+(summary message));
$replace = q(GENERIC $4);

$test =~ s/$search/$replace/;
print $test;
```

This results in ...

```
word1 word2 GENERIC $4
```

NOT

```
word1 word2 GENERIC summary message
```

thanks

Comment: your search pattern won't succeed, there is **!:** at the end of search pattern but not in the string.

Comment: sorry mistake on my part, !: should have been removed from example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double evaluation:

```
$search = q((\S+)\s+(summary message));
$replace = '"GENERIC $1"';

$test =~ s/$search/$replace/ee;
```

Note double quotes in `$replace` and `ee` at the end of `s///`.

Answer (score 0):

try subjecting the regex-sub to eval, be warned that the replacement is coming from external file

```
eval "$test =~ s/$search/$replace/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting solution would use look-aheads `(?=PATTERN)`

Your example would then only replace what needs to be replaced:

```
$test = "word1 word2 servername summary message";

# repl. only ↓THIS↓
$search = qr/\S+\s+(?=summary message)/;
$replace = q(GENERIC );

$test =~ s/$search/$replace/;
print $test;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like amon's solution, I assume that the "GENERIC $1" is not configuration (especially the '$1' part in it). In that case, I think there's an even more simple solution without the use of look-aheads:

```
$test = "word1 word2 servername summary message";
$search = qr/\S+\s+(summary message)/;
$replace = 'GENERIC';
$test =~ s/$search/$replace $1/;
```

Although there's nothing really bad about (?=PATTERN) of course.