# Perl search and replace with variable and capture group

Tags: regex, perl, variables, capture-group

As the question says, I am trying to do a search replace using a variable and a capture group. That is, the replace string contains $1. I followed the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392643/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-replacement-side-of-the-perl-substitution-operator/392717#392717) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469624/perl-passing-regex-search-and-replace-using-variables/11469823#11469823), but they did not working for me; $1 comes through in the replace. Can you help me spot my problem?

I am reading my regular expressions from a file like so:

```
while( my $line = <$file>) {
    my @findRep = split(/:/, $line);
    my $find = $findRep[0];
    my $replace = '"$findRep[2]"'; # This contains the $1
    $allTxt =~ s/$find/$replace/ee;
}
```

If I manually set `my $replace = '"$1 stuff"'` the replace works as expected. I have played around with every single/double quoting and `/e` combination I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using single quotes so `$findRep[2]` isn't interpolated. Try this instead:

```
my $replace = qq{"$findRep[2]"};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why regex replacement when you already have your values in `@findRep`

```
while( my $line = <$file>) {
    my @findRep = split(/:/, $line);
    $findRep[0] = $findRep[2];
    my $allTxt = join(":", @findRep);
}
```

Comment: To clearify, The replace string contains more than just `$1`. It can be any regular expression. I was just honing in on my issue. The replace values with therefore depend on what it matches on in `$allTxt`. The match criteria is specified in `$findRep[0]`. Setting `$findRep[0] = $findRep[2];` would overwrite that.